# cmake add_custom_target not printing to stdout on windows until done with the command

Tags: windows, cmake, stdout

I have a piece of cmake that runs a `add_custom_target()` which takes about a minute to run. When running this command over cmake, stdout only gets printed once the full command is done.

```
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Soft_Dev/590008/JLSCONTROL/JLSOCSOURCE/MASTER/build
Building using cmake
Repo version is: v-0.1.0-902-gffaf1bb-dirty.
[1/2] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\myprogram\build && C:\pclint\lint4jsondb.exe --lint-binary pclp64.exe --jobs 10 -- std.lnt"
```

When I run `cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\myprogram\build && C:\pclint\lint4jsondb.exe --lint-binary pclp64.exe --jobs 10 -- std.lnt"` by myself in a terminal the output gets printed to stdout live while running the command.

Does cmake buffer stdout? If so, is there a way to stop this and let it continue printing while running the custom command?

I am not using any specific arguments at the moment, just the name of the target and then the command with arguments.

```
add_custom_target(LINT_WITH_PC_LINT ${PC_LINT_COMPILECOMMANDS_EXECUTABLE}
--compilation-db compile_commands.json
--lint-path ${PC_LINT_DIRECTORY}
--lint-binary ${PC_LINT_FILENAME}
--jobs 10
-- std.lnt ${PC_LINT_USER_FLAGS})
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can add "USES_TERMINAL" to your custom target.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use the `USES_TERMINAL` argument to _print_ things (at least, according to the simple echo test I just did). I think it's only needed when you need other terminal facilities like input prompts. (citation needed)

Comment: actually, for a simple echo it is not needed, I agree. in my case, `USES_TERMINAL` was in fact necessary, as my command (e.g. cpack) takes naturally long. Thx for sharing, @Komadori!